# How to avoid installing and closing 'HttpResponseCache' on every Activity and Service?

Tags: java, android, caching, networking

I'm developing an Android app which will be compatible with API 14 (Ice Cream Sandwich). I've found the class `HttpResponseCache` which can be used to cache HTTP requests. I want to integrate the cache with my HTTP request code (a common class with a bunch of `public static` methods).
The `HttpResponseCache` documentation explains that the cache has to be installed and closed on every Activity or Service where used. I want the cache to be always enabled on my application but I don't want to remember to install the cache and close it on every new activity I develop.

Is there a pattern to achieve this?

Comment: Really you don't want to remember?  Please consider searching for super and java.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html.  super == remember.

Comment: Actually the [current API doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html) emphasizes the need to *flush* the cache, not to close it. But it doesn't explain how to install and flush a *single* cache for the whole app, which is what your question boils down to. And that's a good answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a process for the application is created, `Application` instance is first created. Installing the cache in `Application`'s `onCreate` method is the best place. `Application.onCreate` method is called before any activity / service / broadcast receiver instance is created.

When an activity is stopped, we need to flush the buffered content to the filesystem, so that cache is readable the next time activity starts. We can register to the activity lifecycle callbacks and call `HttpResponseCache.flush` method in `onActivityStopped` callback.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Install the cache
        try {
           File httpCacheDir = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "http");
           long httpCacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
           HttpResponseCache.install(httpCacheDir, httpCacheSize);
        catch (IOException e) {
           Log.i(TAG, "HTTP response cache installation failed:" + e);
        }

        // Register for activity lifecycle callbacks, 
        // specifically interested in activity stop callbacks.
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(
           new MyApplicationActivityLifeCycleCallbacks());
    }

    // method to flush cache contents to the filesystem
    public void flushCache() {
        HttpResponseCache cache = HttpResponseCache.getInstalled();
        if (cache != null) {
            cache.flush();
        }
    }

    private class MyApplicationActivityLifeCycleCallbacks extends ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
        public void onActivityStopped (Activity activity) {
            flushCache();
        }

        // other methods
    }  
}
```

Above is the basic answer; below are the special cases.

### Services

For services, there is no such generic callback interface. Hence `flush` has to be called from each service's `onDestroy` method.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        MyApplication application = (MyApplication) getApplication();
        application.flushCache();
    }
}
```

Remember to specify the application name in android manifest file's `<application>` tag.

**Alternative solution** : For flushing the content in all your services, you can code a base service which flushes the content in its `onDestroy`. All services in your application can then extend from the base service.

```
public class BaseService extends Service {
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        HttpResponseCache cache = HttpResponseCache.getInstalled();
        if (cache != null) {
            cache.flush();
        }
    }
}

public class MyService extends BaseService {
    ....
}
```

### Closing the cache

If you are particular about closing the cache on the last component exit, you can keep track of number of component instances in your application. The first instance creates the cache and the last instance closes it.

**MyApplication.java** : Keeps track of number of component instances in the application.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private int instanceCount;

    public void incrementInstanceCount() {
        instanceCount++;
    }

    public int decrementInstanceCount() {
        return --instanceCount;
    }
}
```

**BaseActivity.java** : All your activity classes extend this BaseActivity.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if( // cache is not installed ) {
            // install the cache
        }
        getApplication().incrementInstanceCount();
    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // flush the cache
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if( getApplication().decrementInstanceCount() == 0) {
            // close the cache
        }
    }
}
```

**BaseService.java** : Extend all your service classes from BaseService

```
public class BaseService extends Service {
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            if( // cache is not installed ) {
                // install the cache
            }
            getApplication().incrementInstanceCount();
        }

        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();

            if( getApplication().decrementInstanceCount() == 0) {
                // close the cache
            } else {
                // flush the cache
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do the `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` callbacks apply to services too?

Comment: No, there is no such interface for service. You will have to flush cache in service's `onDestroy` method. I've updated my answer on how to do it.

Comment: Thats the idea I had in mind before posting the question but it is repetitive and has a problem; `flush()` will persist the data but you need to `close()` the cache to release the system resources.

Comment: In that case you need to follow 2nd approach for service. Extend the service and flush content in onDestroy. All your service classes can extend from this base service.

Comment: If multiple activities and services use the cache who `close()`s it?

Comment: On application startup, if the cache is already installed and not closed, the contents of cache will be used. The moment you `close` the cache contents will be discarded. Do you still want to `close`? Also there is no specific exit point for android application. It is the responsibility of each component to cleanup the resources allocated by them.

Comment: Thats what I mean, if the `Application` opens the cache is should close it. It is its responsability to cleanup that resource.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60721/discussion-between-manish-mulimani-and-eliocs).

Comment: I will use your counter approach, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 yourConnection.setUseCaches(boolean);
```

Comment: From what I understand that method will allow the connection to use the cache **if it is installed**.